# Perl regular expression to remove leading and trailing whitespace of each column in a string

Tags: perl, qregexp

I have a requirement to remove the leading and trailing spaces in each column of a string delimited by "|"

TEST|               100|            0.00 |TEST STRING
 I am using the following regular expressions to remove the spaces, but it does not seem to work.

```
$data = "TEST|               100|            0.00 |TEST STRING    ";
$data =~ s/(^|\|)\s+/\1/g;
$data =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any code? are you seeing any errors?

Comment: `$data =~ s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;`

Comment: What Matt said, followed by your final line of code `s/\s+$//` to remove any final trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

This should work to remove all trailing and leading spaces for each column data, including the first one.

```
$data = " TEST  |               100|            0.00 |TEST STRING    ";
$data =~ s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;
$data =~ s/\s+$//;
$data =~ s/^\s+//;
print "$data\n";
```